# verifying log rules via elementary properties of an integral

Tags: analysis, definite-integrals

my attempt at this question so far,

$$\int_1^x \frac{1}{t}dt +\int_1^y \frac{1}{t}dt= 2\int_1^x \frac{1}{t}dt+  \int_x^y \frac{1}{t}dt$$
But I am not sure hwo to prove it from elementary properties, I have also tried looking at the graph but the method doesn't seem clear to me.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic property of integrals is the addition of integrals over adjacent intervals of integration:

$$\int_1^{xy}\frac{1}{t}dt=\int_y^{xy}\frac{1}{t}dt+\int_1^{y}\frac{1}{t}dt.$$

Substituting $t=yu$ into the first integral on the RHS, and to obtain the desired identity:

$$\int_y^{xy}\frac{1}{t}dt=\int_{y/y}^{xy/y}\frac{1}{yu}ydu=\int_1^x\frac{1}{u}du.$$

Answer (score 0):

Assume $1<x$, $1<y$:
$$\int_1^{xy} \frac{1}{t}dt = \int_1^x \frac{1}{t}dt+  \int_x^{xy} \frac{1}{t}dt$$

Then in:
 $$\int_x^{xy} \frac{1}{t}dt$$ 
Use $u=\frac{t}{x}$:

$$\int_x^{xy} \frac{1}{t}dt=\int_1^{y} \frac{1}{u}du$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Substitute, $u=t/x$ in the second term. It becomes,

$$\int_x^{xy} \frac{{\rm d}u}{u}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$∫_1^x\frac{1}{t} dt=\ln x- \ln 1=\ln x-0=\ln x$$
Also ,

$$∫_1^y\frac{1}{t} dt=\ln y-ln 1=\ln  y-0=\ln y$$

So

$$∫_1^x\frac{1}{t} dt+∫_1^y\frac{1}{t} dt=\ln x+\ln y$$

We can provide the answer for $\ln x+\ln y$ we use the definition of $\ln x $,$\ln x=\frac{\log x}{\log e}
\ln x+\ln y=\frac{\log x}{\log e}+\frac{\log y}{\log e}=\frac{\log x+\log y}{\log e} =\frac{\log x+\log y}{1}=\ln xy$

$$\ln(xy)=∫_1^xy\frac{1}{t}dt$$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE, we usually use Latex for formatting the posts. By using latex you will be able to express your formulations more elegantly. Please take a look at the changes that I have made to your post to see how small changes improved how it looks. (You can click on edit link above to see my changes)